Trouble Using Jolt Transformer for shift operation on multiple arrays
Sample Input:
[
  {
    "elements": [
      {
        "shadow": {
          "h": 3,
          "v": 2,
          "blur": 1,
          "color": "#808080"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
]

Desired Output:
[
  {
    "elements": [
      {
        "shadow": {
          "offsetX": 3,
          "offsetY": 2,
          "blur": 1,
          "color": "#808080"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
]

Trying to run the following:
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "elements": {
        "*": {
          "shadow": {
            "h": "elements[&1].shadow.offsetX",
            "v": "elements[&1].shadow.offsetY",
            "blur": "elements[&1].shadow.blur",
            "color": "elements[&1].shadow.color"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]

I am either able to successfully convert values within "shadow" or keep "shadow" in the "elements" array. Both events are not happening together. Would love some help!

Welcome to SO, Rashesh

You rather can use a modify spec with overwrite option( modify-overwrite-beta ) such as
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": {// this layer was skipped in the tried spec
        "elements": {
          "*": {
            "shadow": {
              "offsetX": "=(@(1,h))",
              "offsetY": "=(@(1,v))",
              "blur": 1,
              "color": "#808080"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { //get rid of the original attributes
    "operation": "remove",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "elements": {
          "*": {
            "shadow": {
              "h|v": ""
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]

the demo on the site https://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ is :

Indeed, yet you could use shift transformation spec, in the current case the outermost layer is missing, and [&1] should be replaced by [&2] for grabbing the indexes of the "elements" array after 2 levels traversing the tree such as
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "elements": {
          "*": {
            "shadow": {
              "h": "[&4].&3[&2].&1.offsetX",
              "v": "[&4].&3[&2].&1.offsetY",
              "blur|color": "[&4].&3[&2].&1.&"// [&4] represents outermost object
                // &3 stands for "elements"
                // [&2] is for indexes of the "elements" array
                // &1 stands for "shadow"
                // &  stands for the leaf node, replicates the current key's value
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]

the demo follows :


If you want to maintain the array outside you need to add top level *  and then your field assignment will be "[&4].&3[&2].&1.offsetX"...etc.

Exactly @samersaleh I've missed the outermost level for the shift case as well :) Thanks.
